# Having trouble with looping a Switch case and nested while loop

Tags: java, while-loop, switch-statement

I am quite new to programming as this is my first semester in college and no prior knowledge. Working in Java now after working in Python and we are currently working on a fortune telling program. The main issue I'm having is trying to return to the switch to ask if the user would like to play again or if they entered an invalid response that's outside of the 8 cases. Must also have a while loop nested inside another while loop.

```
Scanner user = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Welcome to the Fortune Telling program.\n"); //Welcome message

    System.out.print("Would you like me to tell your fortune? Type 1 for yes and any other number for no: "); //ask for yes or no to run
    int Var0 = user.nextInt();
    if (Var0 == 1)
    {
        System.out.print("Enter a number 1-8 and I will tell your fortune: "); //ask for number between 1-8 to find fortune or invalid
        int Var1 = user.nextInt();                                              
            switch (Var1) 
            {
            case 1:                                                                             //case 1-8 fortunes
                System.out.println("\nYou will become great if you believe in yourself.");
                break;
            case 2:
                System.out.println("\nSerious trouble with bypass you.");
                break;
            case 3:
                System.out.println("\nYou will travel to many exotic places in your lifetime.");
                break;
            case 4:
                System.out.println("\nYour ability for accomplishment will follow with success.");
                break;
            case 5:
                System.out.println("\nWhen fear hurts you, conquer it and defeat it!");
                break;
            case 6:
                System.out.println("\nYou will be called in to fulfill a position of higher honor and responsibility.");
                break;
            case 7:
                System.out.println("\nYour golden opportunity is coming shortly.");
                break;
            case 8:
                System.out.println("\nIntegrity is doing the right thing, even when nobody is watching.");
                break;
            default:
                System.out.print("That's not a valid number. Try again.\n");                         //invalid number try to rerun for correct response
            }
        }                                                                                            //display next print only on case not default
    System.out.print("Would you like another fortune? Type 1 for yes and any other number for no: "); //loop this back into 'switch'
    int Var2= user.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Thank you for trying the fortune telling program.");                           //Thank you message
    user.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: why do you need a nested while loop ?

Comment: it is part of the assignment. But I don't understand where to put it so the user can run the switch again if needed. @Moh123

Comment: Your assignment was probably set by someone who isn't very good at programming. IMHO you should use a `for` loop, not a `while` loop - because you have an iterative aspect (re-asking if the user enters invalid response). Also, the assignment should not dictate an implementation - chosing one is part of learning.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need nested loops. While loop does the job fine. You also need only one Var0 in this which is also a condition to keep / stop the loop. Whole code is inside try-catch block to solve the roblem when user types something which is not int. Finally block at the end closes scanner - no matter if there was and excepion or not.

```
        Scanner user = new Scanner(System.in);
        try {

            System.out.println("Welcome to the Fortune Telling program.\n");
            System.out
                    .print("Would you like me to tell your fortune? Type 1 for yes and any other number for no: ");
            int Var0 = user.nextInt();
            while (Var0 == 1) {
                System.out
                        .print("Enter a number 1-8 and I will tell your fortune: ");
                int Var1 = user.nextInt();
                switch (Var1) {
                case 1: // case 1-8 fortunes
                    System.out
                            .println("\nYou will become great if you believe in yourself.");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    System.out.println("\nSerious trouble with bypass you.");
                    break;
                case 3:
                    System.out
                            .println("\nYou will travel to many exotic places in your lifetime.");
                    break;
                case 4:
                    System.out
                            .println("\nYour ability for accomplishment will follow with success.");
                    break;
                case 5:
                    System.out
                            .println("\nWhen fear hurts you, conquer it and defeat it!");
                    break;
                case 6:
                    System.out
                            .println("\nYou will be called in to fulfill a position of higher honor and responsibility.");
                    break;
                case 7:
                    System.out
                            .println("\nYour golden opportunity is coming shortly.");
                    break;
                case 8:
                    System.out
                            .println("\nIntegrity is doing the right thing, even when nobody is watching.");
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.print("That's not a valid number. Try again.\n");
                }
                System.out
                        .print("Would you like another fortune? Type 1 for yes and any other number for no: ");
                Var0 = user.nextInt();
            }

            System.out
                    .print("Thank you for trying the fortune telling program.");
        } catch (Exception e) {
System.out.println("This is what you tell if user types something which is not a digit");
        } finally {
            user.close();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit of conceptual help:

When you say "I need to return to the switch..." that means you need a loop.

What are the parts that need repeating? The behavior you (or rather, your instructor) are probably expecting is that after telling the fortune, the question "Would you like me to tell your fortune" would appear again. This means that you have to put it, and all that it entails (the fortune telling itself) in a loop.

The usual construct in this case is

- Display question
- Get user input
- Loop, with the condition that the user did not enter the "finish" input

  - Do whatever task the user input requires.
  - Display question again
  - Get user input again, so that the next time the loop checks the condition it will have the fresh value for the calculation.

Can you think of the parts of your program that fit into this pattern?

Now the next thing is that you need a while inside a while. Here is a hint: the program expects the user to enter the values 1-8. If he entered '9' or '0' or whatever, should the program just ignore this and ask him again if he wants the fortune told, or should it insist?

Comment: that actually helped me a lot! I will try and play around with this and figure it out. I really didn't want a direct answer so I could figure it out myself. Next time I reply hopefully it will be corrected. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following. You dont need var1

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Scanner user = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Welcome to the Fortune Telling program.\n"); //Welcome message

    System.out.print("Would you like me to tell your fortune? Type 1 for yes and any other number for no: ");

    int Var0 = 0;

    while(Var0 != -1)
    {
        System.out.print("Enter a number 1-8 and I will tell your fortune or -1 to quit "); //ask for number between 1-8 to find fortune or invalid

        Var0 = user.nextInt();

        switch (Var0) 
        {
        case 1:                                                                             //case 1-8 fortunes
            System.out.println("\nYou will become great if you believe in yourself.");
            break;
        case 2:
            System.out.println("\nSerious trouble with bypass you.");
            break;
        case 3:
            System.out.println("\nYou will travel to many exotic places in your lifetime.");
            break;
        case 4:
            System.out.println("\nYour ability for accomplishment will follow with success.");
            break;
        case 5:
            System.out.println("\nWhen fear hurts you, conquer it and defeat it!");
            break;
        case 6:
            System.out.println("\nYou will be called in to fulfill a position of higher honor and responsibility.");
            break;
        case 7:
            System.out.println("\nYour golden opportunity is coming shortly.");
            break;
        case 8:
            System.out.println("\nIntegrity is doing the right thing, even when nobody is watching.");
            break;
        default:
            System.out.print("That's not a valid number. Try again.\n"); //invalid number try to rerun for correct response
        }

    }
    System.out.print("Thank you for trying the fortune telling program.");//Thank you message
    user.close();
}
```

Enclose the code in a try catch block just make sure you will capture any exception that may occur while using the scanner. close the scanner in a the finally block or even better if you are using java 1.7 and above use try-with-resources.